# filter function does not and seems to conflict with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to compute moving average with filter function in R but it seems this function is not working due to conflict with the dplyr package.
I tried applying library "base" and "stats" after applying dplyr so that I expected filter function to be somehow be available again, 
 but still it show a message "There is no C_cfilter" and does not work. I would like to figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

We need to use `::` as it is masked by the `dplyr` `filter`

```
stats::filter
```

The message when we load the package `dplyr` tells about the masking functions

```
library(dplyr)

#Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

#The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

#filter, lag

#The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

#intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

So, all of these functions without calling tha `packagename::`will have some error

```
filter(1:10, rep(1, 3))
```

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") :    no applicable method for 'filter_'
>   applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

```
stats::filter(1:10, rep(1, 3))
#Time Series:
#Start = 1 
#End = 10 
#Frequency = 1 
#[1] NA  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 NA
```

or would have changed behavior

```
lag(1:10)
#[1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
stats::lag(1:10)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#attr(,"tsp")
#[1] 0 9 1
```

or may not have effect on a particular `class`

```
setdiff(1:5, 1:3)
#[1] 4 5

base::setdiff(1:5, 1:3)
#[1] 4 5
```

but the effect will be there for a different `class`

```
setdiff(data.frame(col1 = 1:5), data.frame(col1 = 1:3))
#  col1
#1    4
#2    5
base::setdiff(data.frame(col1 = 1:5), data.frame(col1 = 1:3))
#  col1
#1    1
#2    2
#3    3
#4    4
#5    5
```

Comment: Your answer is more than perfect. Thank you so much.